# Android devices does not read JSON file, but Unity able to read it. Why?

Tags: android, json, unity-game-engine

I'm using Json/LitJson file to read the database question and answer into my quizzes.

It works without any error on Unity, but after I build it into APK, it did not run properly on the android devices, which the quizzes did not came out after I start it. I'm using MI3 android phone, then I tried it on BlueStacks also. It does not work on both platform(well both of them is android).

I'm not very sure it is the android devices problem or my read Json file code problem. Below is my code to read the Json file. Appreciate any helps. Thanks.

```
void Start(){//start reading Json file
    score = 0;
    nextQuestion = true;
    jsonString = File.ReadAllText (Application.dataPath + "/quiz.json");
    questionData = JsonMapper.ToObject (jsonString);
    //StartCoroutine ("Json");
}



public void OnClick(){//get the question and answer from Json after clicking

    if (nextQuestion) {

        GameObject[] destroyAnswer = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Answer");
        if (destroyAnswer != null) {
            for (int x=0; x<destroyAnswer.Length; x++) {
                DestroyImmediate (destroyAnswer [x]);
            }
        }

        qq.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = questionData ["data"] [questionNumber] ["question"].ToString ();

        for (int i=0; i<questionData["data"][questionNumber]["answer"].Count; i++) {
            GameObject answer = Instantiate (answerPrefab);
            answer.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text = questionData ["data"] [questionNumber] ["answer"] [i].ToString ();
            Transform answerC = GameObject.Find ("GameObject").GetComponent<Transform> ();
            answer.transform.SetParent (answerC);

            string x = i.ToString ();

            if (i == 0) {
                answer.name = "CorrectAnswer";
                answer.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (() => Answer ("0"));
            } else {
                answer.name = "WrongAnswer" + x;
                answer.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (() => Answer (x));
            }
            answer.transform.SetSiblingIndex (Random.Range (0, 3));
        }

        questionNumber++;
        nextQuestion = false;
        clickAns = true;
    }

}
```

My Json file:

```
{
"data": [
{
    "id": "1",
    "question": "Cape Warthog and Dodo come from which country?",
    "answer": [
        "Africa",
        "India",
        "Philippines",
        "Australia"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "question": "Dama Gazelle live in what place?",
    "answer": [
        "Sahara dessert",
        "Africa beach",
        "Rain forest",
        "South pole"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "question": "Why did the Sabertooth Tiger extinct",
    "answer": [
        "overhunting",
        "Habitat loss",
        "Natural polution",
        "Diseases"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "question": "Wolly Mammoth resemblance to which animal?",
    "answer": [
        "Elephant",
        "Tiger",
        "Sheep",
        "Giraffe"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "question": "How big Tasmanian Tiger mouth would open?",
    "answer": [
        "120 degree angle",
        "110 degree angle",
        "100 degree angle",
        "130 degree angle"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "question": "Greak Auk could not fly because it has ..... ?",
    "answer": [
        "Tiny wing",
        "Heavy body",
        "Big head",
        "Large feet"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "question": "PyreneanIbex make their homes at where ? ",
    "answer" : [
        "Cliffs",
        "Caves",
        "Forest",
        "Waterfall"
    ]
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "question": "What are endangered animals?",
    "answer": [
        "Animals that going to extinct",
        "Animals that flys",
        "Animals that are dangerous",
        "Animals that have 4 legs"
    ]
}
]
}
```

Comment: How does the JSON file look? What is the structure of the QuestionData object?

Comment: I have edited into my question. Thanks

Comment: do you get any feedback in logcat?

Comment: what is a logcat? It work without any error on Unity, but unable to work on phone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I was practicing the [Quiz Game 2](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/loading-game-data-json?playlist=17117) from Unity Live Session. You need to code differently for Android. I put my **data.json** file in **StreamingAssets** folder inside Assets folder. It works fine in Unity Editor but the problem is that the [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) folder doesn't exist on android.

On Android, the files are contained within a compressed .jar file (which is essentially the same format as standard zip-compressed files). This means that if you do not use Unity’s [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class to retrieve the file, you need to use additional software to see inside the .jar archive and obtain the file.

Here my code sample; call ***LoadGameData()*** from Start().

```
private void LoadGameData()
{
    string filePath = "";

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    filePath = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/data.json";
    if (File.Exists (filePath)) {

        string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText (filePath);
        GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData> (dataAsJson);

        allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
    } else {
        Debug.LogError ("Can not load game data!");
    }
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    filePath = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/data.json";
    StartCoroutine(GetDataInAndroid(filePath));
    #endif
}

IEnumerator GetDataInAndroid(string url) 
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;
    if (www.text != null) {

        string dataAsJson = www.text;
        GameData loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameData> (dataAsJson);

        allRoundData = loadedData.allRoundData;
    } else {
        Debug.LogError ("Can not load game data!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First place your json file into Resources folder. Create a class and deserialize your json to the class.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

// Put the following in your class
public class QuestionData
{
    public string Question{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Answer{ get; set; }
}

TextAsset jsonTextAsset = Resources.Load("quiz") as TextAsset;
if (jsonTextAsset == null)
{
    Debug.LogError("quiz not found");
    return;
}

string jsonString = jsonTextAsset.text;
var questionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<QuestionData>>(jsonString);
```

You can access json data with questionData List. Here an example of getting random question and assign to TextMeshProUGUI texts.

```
// Assign references via Unity or Script
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI questionText;
[SerializeField] private List<TextMeshProUGUI> answerTexts;

int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, questionData.Count);

questionText.text = questionData[randomIndex].Question;
for (int i = 0; i < questionData[randomIndex].Answer[i].Length; i++)
{
    answerTexts[i].text = questionData[randomIndex].Answer[i];
}
```